# QTest get test name

Tags: c++, qt, qtestlib

Within a Qt Unit-test, how can the program retrieve the name of the test being run?

Code looks something like this:

```
#include <QtTest>
class MyTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private Q_SLOTS:
    void initTestCase()
    {
    }

    void testCase1()
    {
    }

    void cleanupTestCase()
    {
      // Want to print "finished testCase1" here
    }
};

QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN(MyTest)
```

e.g. can it find out the name of the signal/slot that triggered the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QTest::currentTestFunction()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtest.html#currentTestFunction) Should return the name of the current test function as a `const char *`

As an aside, perhaps you want to put it within a `cleanup` function, and not `cleanupTestCase`? It appears that `cleanup` is called after each test, while `cleanupTestCase` will be called only after all tests are finished.